# Cassandra - get all data for a certain time range

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to query a Cassandra database to get records for a certain range?

I have a table definition like this

```
CREATE TABLE domain(
domain_name text,
status int,
last_scanned_date long
PRIMARY KEY(text,last_scanned_date)
)
```

My requirement is to get all the domains which are not scanned in the last 24 hours. I wrote the following query, but this query is not efficient as Cassandra is trying to fetch entire dataset because of `ALLOW FILTERING`

```
SELECT * FROM domain where last_scanned_date<=<last24hourstimeinmillis> ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Then I decided to do it in two queries

1st query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name from domain;
```

2nd query:
Use IN operator to query domains which are not scanned i nlast 24 hours

```
SELECT * FROM domain where 
domain_name IN('domain1','domain2') 
AND 
last_scanned_date<=<last24hourstimeinmillis>
```

My second approach works, but comes with an extra overhead of querying first for distinct values.

Is there any better approach than this?

Answer (score 1):

You should update your structure table definition. Currently, you are selecting domain name as your partition key while you can not have more than 2 billion records in single Cassandra partition.

I would suggest you should use your time as part of your partition key. If you are not going to receive more than 2 billion requests per day. Try to use day since epoch as the partition key. You can do composite partition keys but they won't be helpful for your query.

While  querying you have to scan at max two partitions with an additional filter in a query or in your application filtering out results which do not belong to a 
the range you have specified.

Go over following concepts before finalizing your design.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCompositePartitionKeyConcept.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningPartitionSize.html

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra can effectively perform range queries only inside one partition. The same is for use of the aggregations, such as `DISTINCT`. So in your case you'll need to have only one partition that will contain all data. But that's is bad design.

You may try to split this big partition into smaller ones, by using TLDs as separate partition keys, and perform fetching in parallel from every partition - but this also will lead to imbalance, as some TLDs will have more sites than other.

Another issue with your schema is that you have `last_scanned_date` as clustering column, and this means that when you update `last_scanned_date`, you're effectively insert a new row into database - you'll need to explicitly remove row for previous `last_scanned_date`, otherwise the query `last_scanned_date<=<last24hourstimeinmillis>` will always fetch old rows that you already scanned.

Partially your problem with your current design could be solved by using the Spark that is able to perform effective scanning of full table via token range scan + range scan for every individual row - this will return only data in given time range. Or if you don't want to use Spark, you can perform token range scan in your code, something like [this](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java).

Comment: hello, could you please point me to an example about this: *and perform fetching in parallel from every partition*, also why *but this also will lead to imbalance* and how could I avoid it? In general, I have a table with multi-row partitions (I shortened partition size by adding a week start timestamp) but now I'm unable to range-query that week column since it's part of the partition key. what would you recommend please? reading material or a resource would be great please. thanks